# How to add 0 quantity product to add to cart in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have to display the 0 quantity size product in frontend but addtocart button is missing.
How can i add 0 quantity product to cart in Magento 2?

Comment: You cannot add the product to cart if its quantity is zero. However what you can do is go to backend catalog->products->manage products->select the particular product and increase the quantity of product in inventory and make it in stock. After that clear the cache and check again you will be able to add product in cart

Comment: But my requirements add 0 quantity product to cart

Comment: "Out of stock" product you can add to the cart for this you need to enable `Backorders`.

Comment: Basically, if you add a product to the cart, it means you want to buy it and at least "1" it makes no sense to buy a product with "0" quantity

Comment: @Soundararajanm  you can go to catalog->products->manage products->select the particular product ->advanced inventory->and set backorders to Allow quantity below 0. Then clear cache,run indexing and check it again

Comment: @sugar, in the product view page showing "Out of stock" but i need addtocart button

Comment: @sugar, Once change the stock status as "In Stock" then got addtocart button.

Answer (score 2):

Hello @Soundararajanm,

You cannot add the product to cart if its quantity is zero without backorders being enabled. However what you can do is go to backend **catalog->products->manage products->select the particular product and increase the quantity of product in inventory and make it in stock.** After that clear the cache and check again you will be able to add product in cart.This will make add to cart button enabled for you.

Comment: Yes working fine. Already we commented in above answer

Comment: if it works for you please upvote so that other can also be benefitted from it :)